# Templates and inheritance

Tags: wpf

I have a big problem.
I use additional controls for Wpf. One of them is Telerik RadWindow
This control is already templated.
Now I want to create custom Window with will inherit from RadWindow, and make custom template, eg. One base window will contains grid and two buttons, second base window will contain two grids (master - detail).
The problem is that templates do not support inheritance. Perhaps is another way to template only the content of Winodow?

My code, that doesn't work (empty window appears, so template doesn't apply)

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TBaseRjWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TBaseRjContent}">

                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Grid Name="mGrid">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition   />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition   />
                            <RowDefinition  MaxHeight="40" MinHeight="30"  />

                            <RowDefinition  MaxHeight="40" MinHeight="30"  />
                            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"     />
                            <RowDefinition  MaxHeight="40" MinHeight="30" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <telerik:RadGridView Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="grid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  ScrollMode="Deferred"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"   Width="Auto"   >
                        </telerik:RadGridView>
                        <telerik:RadDataPager Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
      x:Name="radDataPager"
      PageSize="50"
      AutoEllipsisMode="None"
      DisplayMode="First, Previous, Next, Text"
      Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 5 5 5"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >

                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btAdd"  Margin="5 0 5 0"   Content="Dodaj"  />
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btEdit" Margin="5 0 5 0" Content="Edytuj"   />
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btDelete" Margin="5 0 5 0" Content="Usun"   />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Name="addFields" Background="LightGray" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <GroupBox Header="Szczegoly" Margin="2 2 2 2" >
                                <Grid  VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=grid}" Name="_gAddFields" Margin="0 0 0 0"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  >
                                </Grid>
                            </GroupBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="5 5 5 5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btSave"  IsDefault="True" Width="60"  Margin="5 0 5 0" Content="Zapisz"    />
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btOK" IsDefault="True"  Width="60" Margin="5 0 5 0"   Content="Akceptuj"  />
                            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="btCancel" IsCancel="True" Width="60" Margin="5 0 5 0" Content="Anuluj"    />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ContentTemplate` for the `Window`.  It is a `DataTemplate` that will be used to display the `Content` set on the `Window`.